# codeignite trying to get property of non-object not resolved

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am attempting to access the result set from a model query in the view. I have the following:

Controller:

```
           $courseId = $this->session->userdata('courseId');
            //echo "Course: ".$courseId;
            if(isset($courseId) && $courseId != '')
            {           
                $result = $this->Course_model->loadBasicDetailsEdit($courseId);
                $data['basicCourseDetails'] = $result;
                $this->load->view('course/basicDetails', $data);
            }
```

Model:

```
function loadBasicDetailsEdit($courseId)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('course_id', $courseId);    
        $this->db->from('course');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) 
        { 
          return $query->result(); 
        } else { 
            return FALSE;   
        }   
    }
```

and in the view I tried to print_r() and got this:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [course_id] => 8 [title] => Photography [summary] => [description] => [price] => [member_id] => 12 [category] => [audience] => [goals] => [date] => 2013-09-26 [production] => 0 ) )
```

I tried to access this using $basicCourseDetails->title or $basicCourseDetails['title']
but neither are working. Any hint as to why this is happening?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
foreach($basicCourseDetails as $basic){
    echo($basic->title);
}
```

or something like this:

```
echo($basicCourseDetails[0]->title);
```

Comment: Thanks Alessandro, but what if I don't want to loop. Just access it as object attributes?

Comment: Nope that is still throwing trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 0):

This is an array of objects

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [course_id] => 8 [title] => Photography [summary] => [description] => [price] => [member_id] => 12 [category] => [audience] => [goals] => [date] => 2013-09-26 [production] => 0 ) )
```

Contains one `stdObject` in the array, so, first objects is `0`, if there were more, then second item could have index `1` and so on. To retrieve data from the first (here is only one) `stdobject` you may use

```
echo $basicCourseDetails[0]->title; // title will be printed
```

Comment: I want to get rid of the [0]. Is that possible?

Comment: What `0`? The first item index is `0`. To get an indexed item, you have to use the `index` number.

Answer (score 0):

You can send data to the view page by this line of code which is mentioned in above question.

```
$result = $this->Course_model->loadBasicDetailsEdit($courseId);
                $data['basicCourseDetails'] = $result;
                $this->load->view('course/basicDetails', $data);
```

But when you will access these data in view then you need to access all data one by one by using foreachloop in the view page.

For example if you have a view page like basic_details.php inside course folder then you need to write code like this to access these data.

```
foreach ($basicCourseDetails as $key => $value) {
            $name = $value->name;
}
```

The above foreachloop can be written in view page where you want to access data.